# What are good resources for making a Rails 3 app run fast

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance

Now that I have a working Rails 3 web app, I'd like to make it fast. Are there any resources out there that people recommend? In general, I'd like for people to not think something is wrong because the pages are loading slower than they're used to elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential tool for Rails app performance is [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/). Might be overkill for your needs, but well worth checking out.